# Stateless Sessions with Flask and AWS ELB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, flask-login

I have two identical Flask apps deployed on two AWS EC2 instances. I then have an Elastic Load Balancer in front of those two machines.

I'm using Flask's standard cookie based session management for authentication and `@login_required` annotations to secure routes.

Everything works fine with the load balancer set to sticky, but as soon as I start sending a request to the machine that didn't do the initial authentication (not sticky) I get auth errors.

I've got the same secret key in my config for both servers:

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = "my_key"
```

My user is held in the DB:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)
```

Can the Flask encrypted session cookie be shared between different machines in a truly stateless manner?

Comment: Is the secret_key the same for both apps?

Comment: Yep - both flask apps were built out of the same source control branch.